# Rails multi_db sharding middleware not running in production

Tags: sharding, ruby-on-rails-7

I have this in my multi_db.rb file:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.active_record.shard_selector = { lock: true }
  config.active_record.shard_resolver = ->(request) {
    puts "MULTI_DB: subdomain = #{request.subdomain}"
    return request.subdomain == "fr" ? "french": "default"
  }
end
```

Pretty straightforward, trying to route to a different shard based on language. And this works fine locally. Every time I issue a request, I see my puts above print the the debug line. But in prod, I don't see this at all, this code is simply not running.

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this looked to be a version mismatch. I was actually running rails 7.0.4 locally, but prod was running 7.0.2.4. When I updated prod to 7.0.4, things worked fine. Not sure if there was a problem with initializers in 7.0.2.4, or just some version shenanigans.